# AppEngine-OAuth-Library LinkedIn - Grant more permissions

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, python-2.7, linkedin-api

I use the [AppEngine-OAuth-Library](https://github.com/mikeknapp/AppEngine-OAuth-Library/blob/master/oauth.py) to get user information from LinkedIn, but how do I grant for more permissions than the default basic profile.

The LinkedInClient class has this constructer:

```
OAuthClient.__init__(self,
    LINKEDIN,
    consumer_key,
    consumer_secret,
    "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken",
    "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken",
    callback_url)
```

I have tried this instead:

https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress

But it gives an Internal Server Error, when I make a request. It works perfect with the default basicprofile request. Some ideas on what is wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give additional params in the oauth.py. Where you put a dictionary with the key 'Scope' and the value should be the permission you want. If you want more than 1 permission, make a space in the value like so 'r_basicprofile r_emailaddress'